# Android ViewPager invalidate() not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've just started with android development and invalidate the ViewPager is really bugging me :/

Can someone tell me how can i invalidate the ViewPager while changing the orientation.

This is what I've tried so far -

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

     myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.my_pager);
     myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
     myPager.setCurrentScreen(currentPosition, false);
     invalidate();
}
```

The above code is working fine when attached debugging. But it is not working on runtime (without debug mode). I have also tried with sleep but no changes on view.

Can someone explain in detail what is happening here?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some kind of race condition :) try to call invalidate inside a handler and call handler on end of configuration change:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Handler handler = new Handler() 
    { 
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
          {
             invalidate();
          }
    }
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, Even using race condition also not invalidate the view on runtime.

Comment: Try to create a view for landscape and a view for portrait mode in your layout folder.